# CQWP rendering items like http://site/Lists/item/2_.000

Tags: xslt, content-query-web-part

I have a content query webpart, it's rending item url as `http://site/Lists/item/2_.000`, I have to edit the webpart and remove the value of the Url Path, from the link field, then it will work fine, how do I solve this?

Comment: did  you try with the <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"> ?

Comment: for the title itself? why would I want to use that?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the web part in the browser, open up the Presentation section and scroll down towards the bottom of that section.  You will find Fields to Display.  Here you can choose which fields populate which parts of the XSL when it is presented - or remove elements if needed.

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for your reply. but in my requirement, I need to insert the webpart programmatically in a module to many pages, I can't repeat this procedure everywhere, is there some settings that can be changed? something with xsl maybe?

Comment: Yes, you can customise the XSLT but again you need to be able to apply it to multiple pages.  The way I generally work with custom CQWP is to link them to copies the standard XSL files, set them up the way I want them through the settings, then export and import to the web part gallery.  You can then use the web part in multiple pages as with any other web part.  A couple of posts on my blog cover this topic http://paylord.wordpress.com. There may well be other ways to do this through code but I am no developer.

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for your email, yes but my problem is with this rendering thing, I guess we went away of the original target here, what property exactly in the xsl should I alter to modify the rendering of the url to be correct?

Comment: Is the link itself working or is it just the label on the link you want to change?  The easiest is probably for you to edit your question and include an extract of the XSL you are using.